# Ssis empty excel columns causing error

Tags: ssis, mapping

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.
Goal of project
  -create "*\temp\email" directory
  -start program to extract all emails that include xls attachments to the previously created folder
  -use for each loop to cycle through each file in the folder, process, and shift to sql table.
The problem I am running into is caused by either a blank excel document (which is occasionally sent from a remote location) or some of the original xls reports only contain 5 columns instead of 6 that I have mapped now. Is there any way to separate files that include the correct columns from those that do not match?
 ** as Long as these two problems do not exist I can run the ssis package and everything runs without issue.

Control flow;
File System Task (creates directory --->Execute Process Task (xls extraction)-->ForEach Loop(Data flow Task "email2Sql")

Data Flow;
Excel Source (uses expression ExcelFilePath,@user:filepath) delay validation ==true
(columns are initially set to f1-f6 and are mapped to for ex. a,b,c,d,e,f. The Older files that get mixed in only include a,b,c,d,e.) This is where I want to be able to separate the xls files
Conditional Transformation split (column names are not in row 1, this helps remove "null" values)
Ole Db destination (sql table)

Sorry for the amount of reading, but for the first post I tried to include anything that I thought may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools out there which would allow you to open the excel doc and read it.  However, I think the simplest thing to do would be to use SSIS out of the box:

1 - add a file system task after the data flow which reads the file.

2 - Make the precedence constraint from the data flow to the file system task "failure."  This will cause that to only fire when the data flow task fails.

3 - set the file task to move the "bad" files to another folder

This will allow you to loop through all the files and move the failed ones.  Ultimately, the package will end in failure.  If you don't want that behavior you can change the ForceExecutionResult property to be success.  However, it might be good to know that there were problems with some files so that they can be addressed.

m

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mark. I'm sorry it took me a little time to get back to you. New to ssis and wanted to google a few things before responding. I think I understand what you have recommended and so I will try it today and hopefully get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks again. I went through as you suggested and this took care of the problem for me.